# Which method is preferred to override onBackPressed?

Tags: android

**First case**

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
```

**Second case**

```
OnBackPressed();
```

Which case is better to override backKeypress event?

Comment: The main difference is that onKeyDown is since API 1 while OnBackPressed is since API 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to catch the back press prior to 2.0, you can use the `onKeyDown` method like so:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
        //Do something on back press
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Interestingly, if you override both the onBackPressed and onKeyDown, both will catch the back press with `onKeyDown` catching it first.

If you call `super.onKeyDown` in `onKeyDown` like we are above, then the `onBackPressed` method will fire.  If you do not call `super.onKeyDown` then `onBackPressed` will never be called.

Unless you have a specific reason to target below 2.0, there isn’t much of a reason to bother.

Comment: Common that is not too hard to copy the relevant parts.

Comment: I am just showing the difference between both. It's easy to provide the solution, but much of the answers don't provide which one is better to use.

Comment: You are contradicting the obvious. People are ** only ** saying which is better to use. And don't provide much explanation.

Comment: What I wanted to say is that you just dump a link instad of giving a short summary of the article. It is possible that the linked site get offline so your answer would be pointless. So it is better to repeat the main points and give a reference for future informations.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should use:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        //...
    }
```

in case when you just want to override an event. The first method is better if you want to detect that user physically clicked back key.

Comment: for second method --'in case whe you just want to override an event'? and for first method - if we wish to detect if user physicall clicked back key.. does it mean that we could fire this 'backpress event' without even physically clicking back key?

Comment: Yes, you can just call onBackPressed();

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
```

If you are talking overriding this event the first one is the right thing to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    }
```

Comment: Don't provide duplicate answers.

Comment: Ah it seems we were typing at the same time, my bad. My answer is a bit more confident though :P